# postfix-2.10.1-6.el7 daemon startup failure

Tags: postfix, redhat

So I have several RHEL 7.3 servers and am unable to get a untouched postfix daemon to start. I have not changed any of the config files so the service should start just fine it may not work but should at least start.

Here is the output from journalctl -xe of the startup failure

```
-- Unit postfix.service has begun starting up.
Apr 11 23:36:08 postfix/postfix-script[31187]: starting the Postfix mail system

Apr 11 23:36:08 postfix/master[31189]: fatal: 127.0.0.1:smtp: Servname not supported for ai_socktype

Apr 11 23:36:09 postfix/master[31188]: fatal: daemon initialization failure

Apr 11 23:36:10 postfix/postfix-script[31190]: fatal: mail system startup failed

Apr 11 23:36:10 systemd[1]: postfix.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1

Apr 11 23:36:10 systemd[1]: Failed to start Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
-- Subject: Unit postfix.service has failed
```

Here is the postconf information

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

command_directory = /usr/sbin

config_directory = /etc/postfix

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

debug_peer_level = 2

debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin 
ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

html_directory = no

inet_interfaces = localhost

inet_protocols = all

mail_owner = postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port name `smtp` is defined in `/etc/services`:

```
grep smtp /etc/services
```

The Postfix master process reads the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` configuration file to know which Postfix services it should start and control. One of those is the `smtpd` service for receiving mail. The configuration file uses the symbolic name **smtp** to specify on which port this service will be listening. Normally your system should define this and other port names in the file `/etc/services`. But your error message `127.0.0.1:smtp: Servname not supported for ai_socktype` suggests that Postfix could not translate the name into a number. Perhaps the `/etc/services` file does not exist or Postfix cannot read it or it does not contain an entry for `smtp`. In these cases Postfix was probably not to blame and other networking applications on your system might have problems too.